# How to trigger custom logic after TeamCity job failed/was stopped?

Tags: teamcity

I need to trigger custom logic (e.g. shell script) once the TC job fails. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I already found that. It can be achieved by **adding a build step that will be executed even if any of the previous steps failed or were stopped**.